# Pytorch DataLoader output is not iterable

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, dataloader

I am following some tutorials online about Pytorch and it seems at some point I do not get the expected output although I follow everything step by step.

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
Train = datasets.MNIST("", train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
Test = datasets.MNIST("", train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
trainset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Train, batch_size= 10, shuffle=True)
testset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Test, batch_size= 10, shuffle=True)
```

But then when I try to loop through trainset I receive the following error:

```
for ii in trainset:
    print(ii)
    break

TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can anyone tell me why do I get this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is this the whole code? if not please check in Python you should add self argument as the first argument to all defined methods in classes

Comment: It's a bug, try downgrade `pillow` or `numpy`.

Comment: @prithviparre, yes this is the whole code and there is no class here.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen, Well shouldn't this be in the documentation. downgrading does sound to be the right way to go.

Comment: It's like how the `async` broke a lot of things when python 3.7 came out. Soon it'll be patched but now better use pillow 8.2.0